# como puedo lograr crear un documento con itextpdf sin que netbeans me marque un error

Tags: java, mysql, itextpdf

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito generar un documento en netbeans pdf en escritorio con ayuda de netbeans y creado en msql con itextpdf pero el programa me marca error al ejecutarlo y no me crea el documento que hago que debo saber y hacer para que netbeans me genere el documento itextpdf

Comment: Bienvenido a SOe. Por favor: 1) Pon el código como texto y 2) Explica bien el error que te da y, si es una excepción, en que línea salta. Revisa [ask]

Comment: Este es el codigo   Connection cn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/bd_ins", "root", ""); y la parte que me señala en rojo y en error es  .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/bd_ins", "root", "") y no corre el programa por eso